# Check and delete consecutive ips /numbers

Tags: javascript, php, excel

Hi need an excel formula to remove consecutive ips from text file as column listed.

how it is right now:

```
 - 141.101.x.18,
   141.105.x.161,
   141.105.x.162,
   141.105.x.163,
   141.105.x.185,
   141.105.x.204,
   141.105.x.205,
   141.105.x.206,
```

how i need it:

```
141.101.x.18,
141.105.x.185
```

It could be in excel, php, javascript I just need to clean a list with tons of data.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: in php - `implode(', ', array_unique(explode(', '  $str)));`

Comment: excel formula? text file? and tagged php\javascript .. so what language do you want?

Comment: It could be in any language.

Comment: ok, let me write something in assembler for you ;)

Comment: @rtfm or in English how to remove consecutive IPs :-)

Comment: Is x.x.1.255 and x.x.2.1 consecutive numbers?

Comment: @Andreas I thought that this was a community to get help, Maybe I came to the wrong place, and no those arent consecutive but thats not part of my example. thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @daultimate yes you can get help here. IF you follow the rules. Jay commented with a list of links. Read them. Then come back and ask the question again in a correct manner.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Excel

With data in column **A** try this short VBA macro:

```
Sub dataKiller()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, rDel As Range
    Set rDel = Nothing
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If vl(Cells(i, 1)) = vl(Cells(i - 1, 1)) + 1 Then
            If rDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rDel = Union(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1))
            Else
                Set rDel = Union(rDel, Cells(i, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    rDel.Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub

Public Function vl(s As String) As Long
    vl = CLng(Replace(Split(s, ".")(3), ",", ""))
End Function
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

The `vl()` UDF extracts that last number in each value.

Comment: It works. thank you so much.